# Progress bar doesn't update programatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a progress bar, that should start out as invisible, become visible upon clicking, and then become invisible again.

The issue seems to be in the block of code, inserted after the progress bar. It calls an api, and gets the results, taking around 4 seconds. If i comment out that bit of code, it works like a charm, but when its included, the setting of the progress bar to visible doesn't work.

Ideally, the code should set the progress bar visible at the beginning of the function, and then set it invisible again at the end of it.

```
private void btnProvjeriRate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var txtRateUnosBroja = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtRateUnosBroja);
            var txtRateUnosJMBG = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtRateJMBG);

            ProgressBar progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);
            progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

            if (Util.Functions.validateJMBG(txtRateUnosJMBG.Text)) {

                if (Util.Functions.ValidatePhoneNumber(txtRateUnosBroja.Text))
                {
                //block of code
                }
                else
                {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Util.Functions.generateNotification(FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content), "Neispravan format broja");
                    snackbar.Show();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Snackbar snackbar = Util.Functions.generateNotification(FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content), "Neispravno unesen JMBG");
                snackbar.Show();
            }


        }
```

Comment: UI can’t update until your code relinquishes control of cpu. Read about async/await. Or run the slow code on a background thread. These are two standard c# techniques for allowing UI to get time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `AsyncTask` to achieve this.

Please refer to the following code:

`activity_main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`MainActivity.cs`

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    ProgressBar pb;
    TextView tv;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        pb = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.pb);
        tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
        UpdatePB uptask = new UpdatePB(this,pb,tv);
        uptask.Execute(100);
    }
}
```

`UpdatePB.cs`

```
   public class UpdatePB : AsyncTask<int, int, string>
    {
        Activity mcontext;
        ProgressBar mpb;
        TextView mtv;
        public UpdatePB(Activity context,ProgressBar pb,TextView tv) {
            this.mcontext = context;
            this.mpb = pb;
            this.mtv = tv;
        }
        protected override string RunInBackground(params int[] @params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Android.Util.Log.Error("lv",e.Message);
                }
                mpb.IncrementProgressBy(25);
                PublishProgress(i * 25);

            }
            return "finish";
        }

        protected override void OnProgressUpdate(params int[] values)
        {
            mtv.Text = String.ValueOf(values[0]);
            Android.Util.Log.Error("lv==", values[0] + "");
        }
        protected override void OnPostExecute(string result)
        {
            mcontext.Title = result;
        }
       
    }
```

**Note:**

You can try to add your time-consuming code to method `RunInBackground` of class `UpdatePB` .